# Zend Framework issue with Local instance of Site

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I've little to no experience working with `Zend Framework 1` . Recently I was asked to make some changes to a sites functionality. So I decided that I would set up a local instance of the site to work on before deploying the changes to the live site.

The problem I am having is that when I go to the following `url` which is my local instance of the site: http://mysite.tld I am redirected to https://mysite.ie and I cannot figure out why.

Is it something to do with the `htaccess` file? because I removed the contents of this file in order to see if it had any impact and no joy.

Which made me thing that perhaps in `Zend` there is some setting which controls the `environment`?

This is my `vhosts` file on WAMP:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\mysite.tld\public
    ServerName mysite.tld
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.tld"
    CustomLog "logs/mysite.tld" common
    <directory "C:\wamp\www\mysite.tld\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If you require any more details from the project I can post them here, I'd appreciate any help as I am at a loss as to whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule performs the redirect from `http` to `https` equivalent

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This one redirects to `www.mysite.tld` if domain name is not already that one

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you're running it locally, you should comment those 4 lines of code.
**Then**, you have to clear your browser's cache to see it working (because your old rules are now in cache).

Comment: Thank you, solved the problem. Will accept answer in 5 mins time.